# gcc. как скомпилировать код СИ в iso/img

Tags: c, gcc, ос, dd

Привет всем не ровно душным. Недавно решил поиграться с вбоксом и решил почему бы не попробовать написать ОС на СИ и только на СИ. С написанием проблем не будет, а вот с компиляцией.. пытался и всях и так. `dd`. В общем скажите как мне скомпилировать мой код в образ? Ну и естественно я использую линукс, дебиан с кде плазмой, 64бит

Comment: ISO и IMG это файлы образов диска. В них компилировать не нужно ;) Компилировать нужно в файл, впоследствии который помещать в образ. Для этого есть разные утилиты UltraISO к примеру. В этом образе так же есть загрузочный сектор, в который можно записать загрузчик ОС. Там в этом загрузчике есть своя система, про которую нужно почитать отдельно. В DOSBox тоже есть команда IMAGE (по моему) которая может сформировать IMG файл, но у меня не получилось с него загрузится :) Там свои тонкости в DOSBox.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Очень признателен.

Comment: Вы по какому-то туториалу идете? Там не пишут, как компилировать?